# keycloak redirect url for reverse proxy

Tags: spring-security, apache2, reverse-proxy, keycloak

i have keycloak running in one VM with

> keycloak.domain.com

i have client app which is running on another VM which is running on tomcat like

> app.domain.com

Which is using Spring Security so i done the configuration as below in keycloak.json

```
    {
  "realm": "demo",
  "auth-server-url": "http://keycloak.domain.com:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "app-client",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "9503a597-4c83-44ca-884e-e285891a2d32"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

and we have some other service so we have configured Apache reverse Proxy like

> main.domain.com

when i access the main.domain.com/app we are doing proxy as below

```
ProxyPass /app http://app.domain.com/app nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /app http://app.domain.com/app
```

we are able to redirect to keycloak but `redirect_uri` is `http://app.domain.com/app/sso/login` it should go though proxy

Where to configure this? or i am doing it in wrong way? is their anyother way of achiveing OAuth for the my app?

Comment: Did you find the solution of this? We're facing the same thing. Thnaks!

Answer (score 1):

We've managed to solve the issue by setting `ProxyPreserveHost On` in the apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

This set's the `Host` header in the request and the adapter takes care of the rest.
We're using the Servlet Keycloak adapter, but I guess it should work for other adapters as well.